# Should I use authentication on both Reactjs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux

When a user logs in, I store the login variable in redux but when we hit the api request then firstly react.js checks the authentication using redux if loggedin then the node.js checks the authentication and returns the api.

Isn't it unnecessary using authentication on both sides? Why can't I just use authentication on server side only?
Your thoughts please on what should I follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need not to authenticate both side. You have to just send token in headers (authentication) of every API and create middleware for authenticate user for API in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to implement authentication in you're front end projects though the most common way to do this is by using JWT (json web tokens) however for using this type of authentication you need to implement OAuth, OpenID connect or similar authentication service on you're backend .
ps: I recommend storing you're login credentials in cookies